# Reading date from string format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have to read a date in this format in c#

```
yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
```

I cannot change the format because is written by another application
The date is a string like

```
2009/11/17 12.31.35
```

How i can read this format without parsing it(without split if possible)

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by reading date?

Comment: **Without** parsing? Hard to convert a string to a date without parsing! ;)

Comment: Is it `DateTime` or `string`?

Comment: @Adriano I think he meant without parsing the string manually

Comment: @AlexBarac yes, probably. It was a kind of joke but monday humor isn't such good... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot change the format because is written by another application

**Solution 1:** You don't need to change the format for reading it.

Try This:

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy/MM/dd HH.mm.ss", 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

**OR**

> How i can read this format without parsing it(without split if
>   possible)

**Solution 2:** If you want to extract the values from the date string.

Try This:

```
string str = "2009/11/17 12.31.35";

string year = str.Substring(0, 4);    //2009
string month = str.Substring(5, 2);   //11
string date = str.Substring(8, 2);    //17
string Hours = str.Substring(11, 2);  //12
string minutes = str.Substring(14, 2);//31
string seconds = str.Substring(17, 2);//35
```

Comment: I think this is against the OPs requirement, which is to _not_ parse the string

Comment: @AlexBarac: thats why there is `Solution2`

Comment: Solution 2 is also parsing the string, at least in my opinion. And it's also a bit hard-coded, concerning the position of the date/time separators. The first solution is the better one in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`, where you can supply your custom date format

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `.` with `:` an then `ParseExtract`

```
string dt= "2009/11/17 12.31.35";
var dt2=   ss.Replace('.', ':');
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(dt2, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or just

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("2009/11/17 12.31.35", "yyyy/MM/dd HH.mm.ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```